# How to find whether given date range present in the list of Date Ranges in SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to write a stored procedure to find whether the given date range is **overlapping** the list of Date Ranges in the table.

Ex)

Database: SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SP Input: 2012-12-17 18:30:00.000       2012-12-19 18:29:59.000

SP Output(Out parameter): True/False
```

**Booking Table Sample Data:**

```
FromDate                    ToDate

2012-12-11 18:30:00.000     2012-12-12 18:29:59.000
2012-12-12 18:30:00.000     2012-12-13 18:29:59.000
2012-12-10 18:30:00.000     2012-12-11 18:29:59.000
2012-12-18 18:30:00.000     2012-12-19 18:29:59.000
2012-12-23 18:30:00.000     2012-12-28 18:29:59.000
2012-12-17 18:30:00.000     2012-12-18 18:29:59.000
2012-12-19 18:30:00.000     2012-12-22 18:29:59.000
2012-12-16 18:30:00.000     2012-12-17 18:29:59.000
2012-12-13 18:30:00.000     2012-12-14 18:29:59.000
2012-12-11 23:00:00.000     2012-12-12 22:59:59.000
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
USE [BookingDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindConflict]    
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @IsConflict bit OUT
AS

BEGIN

?????????????????????(what to write here)

END
```

SQL:

```
USE [BookingDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookingAdmin](
    [PK_BookingAdmin] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BookingAdmin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_BookingAdmin] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ON
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1048, CAST(0x0000A1240130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1250130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1049, CAST(0x0000A1250130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1260130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1050, CAST(0x0000A1230130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1240130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1051, CAST(0x0000A12B0130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A12C0130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1052, CAST(0x0000A1300130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1350130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1053, CAST(0x0000A12A0130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A12B0130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1055, CAST(0x0000A12C0130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A12F0130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1056, CAST(0x0000A1290130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A12A0130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1057, CAST(0x0000A1260130DEE0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A1270130DDB4 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[BookingAdmin] ([PK_BookingAdmin], [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (1058, CAST(0x0000A124017B0740 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A125017B0614 AS DateTime))
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindConflict]    
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @IsConflict bit OUT
AS
BEGIN
    if exists (select * from BookingAdmin where FromDate = @ToDate and ToDate = @FromDate)
        set @IsConflict = 1   
    else
        set @IsConflict = 0        
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your needs correctly, and you just need to check if there's exactly the same range in the table, you can try this

```
USE [BookingDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindConflict]    
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @IsConflict bit OUT
AS
BEGIN
    if exists (select * from <your table> where FromDate = @FromDate and ToDate = @ToDate)
        set @IsConflict = 1   
    else
        set @IsConflict = 0
END
```

**update** if you want to know about overlapping ranges, try this

```
 ...
    if exists (select * from <your table> where FromDate <= @ToDate and ToDate >= @FromDate)
        set @IsConflict = 1   
    else
        set @IsConflict = 0
 ...
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b63b04/1)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But I need to find the whether the given date range is overlapping with the list of date ranges in database.

Comment: added SQL fiddle example. Could you give me an example on which it's not working?

Comment: I'm sorry If I'm wrong. exec FindConflict
    FromDate = '2012-12-17 15:30:00.000',
    ToDate = '2012-12-17 18:29:59.000',
    IsConflict = IsConflict out also conflict? Because i'm getting 1 for this. (Removed all @ )

Comment: I have updated my question. Included the query to create the table and stored procedure I used

Comment: well there's range in table where FromDate = `2012-12-16 18:30:00.000` and ToDate = `2012-12-17 18:29:59.000` and your range is overlapping with this range.